# Magick.NET in Azure converting SVG to PNG gives black boxes

Tags: azure, svg, imagemagick, magick.net

Using `Magick.NET-Q16-AnyCPU` I am converting an SVG to PNG with this minimal code:

```cs
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("test.svg");
var magickReadSettings = new MagickReadSettings { Format = MagickFormat.Svg };
using var image = new MagickImage(bytes, magickReadSettings) { Format = MagickFormat.Png };
image.Write("test.png");
```

Locally that works fine, and the PNG looks correct having a text (expected):

[image: PNG local]

But when deployed to an Azure App Service, the PNG gets black boxes (actual):

[image]

The SVG file looks like this (minimal):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"[]>
<svg width="100px" height="50px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" version="1.1">
    <g transform="translate(10, 10)">
    <text transform="translate(50, 0)">foo</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

How can that be?

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue related to fonts installed on App Service. There is a [discussion of this issue and resolution at the bottom of the discussion here](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/issues/501).

Comment: Thanks. I tried that resolution, but using the Msvg format I didn't even manage to get a proper image at all (regardless of the black boxes). I ended up using [SVG.NET](https://github.com/vvvv/SVG) and its `Draw()` method.